# In Excel, how do I multiply separated values with separated values in another column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2013

I have two columns of data. Column A contains the items, column B contains the quantity of the items. In the beneath example I would like to count the amount of "forks":

```
 - A1: spoon|fork|knife
 - A2: spoon|bottle|fork|piston
 - B1: 2|1|1
 - B2: 6|2|4|3
```

Or see the image below:

[image: image in excel-screenshot]

In total there would be five forks; one fork in row 1, and five forks in row 2.

How would I count this total amount of forks?

Comment: does the image correspond to what you actually have?

Comment: Yes, that is totally correct! How would I sum up the "1" in B1 and "4" in B2?

Comment: If you want to do math on this, this is just about the worst way to store things I can think of.  You need to decode every cell before you can do anything with it, and decode it again for each action.  If you want to have Excel do anything with this content, my advice would be to parse the cells into individual entries and then use Excel normally to do this in a simple way.

Comment: I second @fixer1234 's opinion. It would be too difficult to work on this data on Excel. What other options do you have? Or as a work-around measure - how many items do you have `spoons, fork, knife, pistons` etc?... how many of them?

Answer (score 0):

This is one way you could do it. I'm assuming you are copying and pasting it from somewhere else.

1. Instead of bringing your data into Excel, save your original data as a .txt file.
2. Open Excel and open a new blank workbook.
3. Under the data ribbon, use the "Get External Data" "From Text" option (left side)
4. Select your .txt file that you saved, you will come to the Text Import Wizard.
5. In step 1, select "Delimited"
6. In step 2, select "Other" and then type the delimiter character you are using (in your case its "|").
7. Skip step 3 by clicking Finish.
8. Choose "New Worksheet" as your output destination

   Now your data will be in a slightly better format. Note, you can do the above steps using the "Text to Columns" function if the data is already in Excel.
9. In Sheet1 (or any blank sheet), make column headings:

   - A1: ITEM
   - A2: QUANTITY
10. Now here's how you turn the sideways mixed up data in to usable data:

    In A2, put this formula:

    ```
    =OFFSET(Sheet4!$A$1,INT((ROW()-2)/4),MOD(ROW()-2,4))
    ```

    - Make sure you replace `"Sheet4!$A$1"` with the cell where your ITEM data starts. In your example this would be the cell with the first "spoon"
    - Make sure you have the dollar signs (i.e. not `A1`, but `$A$1`)
    - If needed, replace the number 4 in the formula with how many columns there are of item data, in your case the max was 4)
11. In B2, repeat what you did in A2, except replace the `"Sheet4!$A$1"` with the cell where your QUANTITY data starts. For me, it looks like this:

    ```
    =OFFSET(Sheet4!$E$1,INT((ROW()-2)/4),MOD(ROW()-2,4))
    ```
12. Now all you have to do is fill down this formula until you have a row for each Item/Quantity combination. With your example, it looks like this:

    ```
    ITEM    QUANTITY
    spoon   2
    fork    1
    knife   1
    0       0
    spoon   6
    bottle  2
    fork    4
    piston  3
    ```
13. Next, copy column A from the above result and past it to a NEW blank sheet in the same workbook. (I'm using Sheet2)
14. While the pasted data is still selected, under the Data ribbon, choose "Remove Duplicates"
15. In the dialog that comes up, check the "My data has headers" box and click OK

    You should have this now:

    ```
    ITEM  
    spoon  
    fork  
    knife  
    0  
    spoon  
    bottle
    ```
16. In B1 create a column header "QUANTITY"
17. In B2 put the following formula:

    ```
    =SUMIF(Sheet1!$A:$A,$A2,Sheet1!$B:$B)
    ```

    Make sure you replace "Sheet1" with whatever sheet you used for the first formulas.

Here is the result!

```
ITEM    QUANTITY  
spoon   8  
fork    5  
knife   1  
0       0  <-- Go ahead and delete this row if you want!  
spoon   8  
bottle  2
```

You could save this Excel workbook and re-use for future data imports as long as you keep putting the imported text data in the same location and the number of columns don't change. If they do just update the formulas accordingly.

As others have pointed out, this is a bizarre data format to start with, but I assume those are the constraints you are stuck with.

Answer (score 0):

Use `COUNTIF`.  For example,in row 9 type: `=COUNTIF(A1:A7, "star")` and then you will see the number of occurrences.

[image]

Also, you can use excellent online-tool: http://string-functions.com/countsubstrings.aspx (in first field, type the desired word, i.e. `fork`, and then insert text below there)

([source](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/count-text-occurrences.html))

Comment: This approach isn't applicable to the question because the data isn't in this form.